# hashing value - decode two value that were used to make it

Tags: java, hash

I am working on a un-directed graph problem. I want to calculate a single number for two neighboring vertices and store it into an array. When reading from the array I would like to exctract the two original vertex keys so I can say that vertex 1 neighbors vertex 2 and vertex 2 neighbors vertex 1.

example:
vertex 1 neighbors vertex 2 - > store some value that captures this relationship 
-> read that number -> print vertex 1, print vertex 2

currently I use the following function (x = vertex 1, y = vertex 2). I would need a decode function fullfilling above requirement. Is that possible ?

```
// converts pair (x, y) to single integer value
long code(int x, int y) {
    return ((1L * x) << 32) | y; // original
}
```

Thanks

Rupert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you will have a problem if `y` is negative. The bitwise or operation will overwrite the encoded `x` with all 1 bits. You should bitwise-and the y value with `0xFFFFFFFF` before the bitwise or with the result.

```
// converts pair (x, y) to single integer value
long code(int x, int y) {
    return ((1L * x) << 32) | ((1L * y) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

- `y` can be recovered from `value & 0xFFFFFFFF`
- `x` can be recovered from `value >> 32`

---

```
static long encodeXY(int x, int y) {
    return ((1L * x) << 32) | ((1L * y) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

static int decodeY(long value) {
    return (int)(value & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

static int decodeX(long value) {
    return (int)(value >> 32);
}
```

Test case:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    long chk = encodeXY(123, 456);
    System.out.println(decodeX(chk));
    System.out.println(decodeY(chk));
}
```

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/ZLgHu1)

If you need to recover negative numbers, then the `y` value needs special handling. If bit 31 is set, then you should bitwise-or the resulting `y` with `0xFFFFFFFF00000000`, assuming you keep it `long`. This is known as [sign-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Comment: unfortunately with this I cant recover y :( maybe I code incorrectly decode:
'code
    int decode(long code) {
        long y =  code & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        long x = code >> 32;
        return 0;
    }

Comment: I added an implementation.